# Binding any key combination to move spaces shortcuts

Tags: macos, shortcut

Is it possible to edit the keyboard shortcuts so it can be a combination of a modifier key and a mouse button?
[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]
I would like to change *Move left a space* to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse 5</kbd> and *Move right a space* to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse 4</kbd>.

I would like to do it natively without having to install third-party applications like Karabiner if possible.
[image]

Comment: What clicks/keys do mouse 4 & 5 provide right now? You can always enter those from the keyboard, then the mouse will send them correctly afterwards, even though the shortcut won't directly accept a mouse-click as input.

Comment: They produce `Mouse Button 4` and `Mouse Button 5` clicks. See new screenshot.

Comment: Ah... right - then it's 3rd party time, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You have (a few years ago) addressed a general issue with MacOS' AppleScript that's been haunting me forever…
So I started a web search –kind of *feasibility study*– naturally stumbled upon **python** and hunted for code samples to make **AS** aware of mouse events. Here is what I attempted to construct:

```
A:    A simple AppleScript (> "AS") to start (and end) the "watchout":

on idle {}
    set repCount to 4
    repeat while repCount>0
        set thescript to "python '/Users/someUser/someFolder/Mouse±Key.py'"
        set xYz to do shell script thescript
        set repCount to RepCount - 1
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    display dialog "Now: " & (repCount as string) & " runs left…"
end idle
```

… which will run **"Mouse±Key.py"** in a loop, limited by **"repCount"** to 5 runs.

Next I started to look into **python** and find ways to detect mouse+key events. It turned out that a **module "pynput"** would have to be installed to your (my) **python** installation:

```
python -m pip install pynput
```

was recommended for this, so I had to install **pip** first. *Well …*

The actual ***.py script** is not very long, due to my *criminal neglect of error handling* and others.
(As I mentioned: *This is a **FEASABILITY study!*** )

Here comes the script – ***BUT:*** as I'm no software engineer I won't be able to explain (with authority) why any one special expression is formulated or positioned the way it is. *(trial-and-erroooors…)*

```
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import os

def on_press(key):
    global keyDown
    if key == Key.shift:
        keyDown = "57.shift"
    else:
        keyDown = "none"

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global keyDown
    if button.value[1] == 3 and keyDown == "57.shift":
        cmd = """
        osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" \n key code 123 using {control down}\n delay 0.5\n end tell' 
        """
        os.system(cmd)
    elif button.value[1] == 4 and keyDown == "57.shift":
        cmd = """
        osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" \n key code 124 using {control down}\n delay 0.5\n end tell' 
        """
        os.system(cmd)

    if not pressed:
        listener_key.stop()
        listener_mouse.stop()

listener_key = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener_key.start()
listener_mouse = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener_mouse.start()
keyDown = "none "
key = "X"

if keyDown == "57.shift":
    listener_key.stop()

listener_key.join()
listener_mouse.join()
```

Okay, what I –as layman– ***can*** say:

 First 3 lines import **pynput modules** (not sure, why **keyboard** and **mouse** separately) & **os**.

 Next, 2 crucial functions **on_press** and **on_click** are defined;
***(keyboard** also supports **on_release**, **mouse** can handle **on_scroll** and **on_move** events.)*

 Between these functions but also in the main thread (therefore **global**) my variable **"keyDown"** "transports" information whether the **key** recognized as **Key.shift** was **pressed**. I named its content **"57.shift"** like AS' "shift" key code.

 I needed **"keyDown"** as I decided to let the **on_press** function only do the key recognition while **on_click** evaluates the **key**, decides what action to take and for the current "run" **stop**s the Listeners.

 The imported **module os** comes into play when the **on_… functions** call *"back"* to **MacOS'** application **"System Events"** via 2 **osascripts** (= **Open Scripting Architecture** language), as AppleScrips.

 The **osascripts** instruct **MacOS'** own system to invoke 2 "integrated" **Mission Control** (arrow-key) shortcuts that will switch to left-side (key code 123) and right-side (124) spaces (s.t. called *"Desktops"*).

 At the end of the **on_click** function 2 different **Listener**s appear, actually to *stop* their listening (once the osa/AppleScript has worked).

 Next, **keyboard.Listener** and **mouse.Listener** are eventually defined and **start()** ed;
these on the other hand are brought into connection with the 2 vital functions.

 Remaining code first defines **"keyDown"** delivers a dummy starting value for **key** and finally *"joins"* both Listener threads so they *"wait"* for each other (simply said).

   I mainly researched these codes from pure interest; for testing purposes (unfortunately I use a MacBook with no buttons 4 and 5) I used this line: `print(key, "(", button.value[1], ")", keyDown+" >>  ", button)`.

**WARNING:** *As there is no error handling strange things may happen if you experiment my code!*

*( Anybody more softwarely educated than me is welcome to improve or comment my efforts, but please leave my bullet list mostly as is.)*

Comment: Having finished this thing, a few questions remain with me, first things first:  WHY do "key" und "listener" habe to be imported "separately" once more although " pynput.Keyboard" already WAS??? ... Most codes on the web used "with pynput.mouse ..." - - my choice worked better: WHY??? ... I lost some time with "subprocess module" which did NOT allow me use some AppleScript system commands: HOW to apply "subprocess" so it is not DISABLING AS commands???