# Can I create a new shortcut for my mission control

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, shortcut, mission-control

Currently there is a shortcut ^ + <- to move left a space but I also want to map ^ + mousebutton5 to do the same thing as well so my right hand does not need to touch the keyboard. Is there a way to do that? I do not see it in the system preferences.

[image: keyboard shortcut menu for Big Sur 11.6]

Comment: If the mouse provides it own software and has that capability to do so, then yes, otherwise probably no.

Comment: I've just posted an answer here, gut ist's Mode experimental.  IF YOU know some Python it might give you ideas:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249968/binding-any-key-combination-to-move-spaces-shortcuts/430521#430521